# Are recursive types really the only way to build noncontinuous arbitrary-size data structures?

Tags: c++, data-structures, language-agnostic

I just noticed a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12113005/430766) asking what recursive data types ("self-referential types") would be good for in C++ and I was tempted to boldly claim

> It's the only way to construct data structures (more precisely containers) that can accept arbitrary large data collections without using continuous memory areas.

That is, if you had no random-access arrays, you would require some means of references (logically) to a type within that type (obviously, instead of having a `MyClass* next` member you could say `void* next` but that would still point to a `MyClass` object or a derived type).

However, I am careful with absolute statements -- just because I couldn't think of something doesn't mean it's not possible, so **am I overlooking something**? Are there data structures that are *neither* organised using mechanisms similar to linked lists / trees *nor* using continuous sequences exclusively?

---

***Note***: This is tagged both [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) as I'd be interested specifically in the C++ language but also in theoretical aspects.

Comment: +1 for this question which made me *seriously* think.... and I'm still thinking, and wondering.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm still waiting for some halfwit to remove the `language-agnostic` tag without reading the question :)

Comment: tbh idk if i get  what you mean , but what about std::deque

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's the only way to construct data structures (more precisely containers) that can accept arbitrary large data collections without using continuous memory areas.

After contemplating for a while, this statement seems be correct. It is self-evident, in fact.

Suppose I've a collection of elements in a *non-contiguous* memory. Also suppose that I'm currently at element `e`. Now the question is, how would I know the *next* element in the collection? Is there any way?

Given an element `e` from a collection, there are *only* two ways to *compute* the location of the next element:

- If I assume that it is at offset `sizeof(e)` irrespective of what `e` is, then it means that the next element starts where the current element ends. But then this implies that the collection is in a *contiguous* memory, which is forbidden in this discussion.
- The element `e` itself tells us the location of the next element. It may store the address itself, or an offset. Either way, it is using the concept of self-reference, which too is forbidden in this discussion.

As I see it, the **underlying idea** of both of these approaches is *exactly same*: they both implement self-reference. The only difference is that in the former, the self-reference is implemented implicitly, using `sizeof(e)` as *offset*. This implicit self-reference is supported by the language itself, and implemented by the compiler. In the latter, it is explicit, everything is done by the programmer himself, as now the *offset* (or pointer) is stored in the element itself.

Hence, I don't see any third approach to implement self-reference. If not self-reference, then what *terminology* would one use to describe the computation of the location of the next element to an element `e`.

So my conclusion is, your statement is absolutely correct.

Comment: Now I'm biased to accept your glorious assertions that I'm correct. I'll give it a day to see if somebody is able to contradict us. :)

Comment: @bitmask: Edited with my explanation.

Comment: This is not entirely true, only on the premise of the usual memory model. If you have, you could, for example use a transactional memory approach where a *pointer* has to be combined with a *generation* to actually access the data. For a slightly more realistic option consider a file backed data structure where you memory map only one block, and you move to the next element by remapping a different section of the file (i.e. the next element is in the exact same location in memory after the file is remapped). The problem is that the question is ill-posed.

Comment: Whereas my answer objected to the notion of "non-contiguous" memory since existing computing architectures ultimately use contiguous memory, your answer is attacking the term "self-reference". However, it was the OP that said "linked-list / tree", which implies the container is searchable. And, you must have a key to do a search. By your assertion, the search key itself would make the container self-referential. If that is not what you meant, then the search key would be a non self-referential way to specify "next".

Comment: @user315052 A linked list is not searchable any more than an array is searchable. It is simple a collection, and so is a tree. You can treat the elements (or parts of them) as key for search algorithms, or you can choose not to do so.

Comment: @delnan: Then the question itself is not well formed since the proof of correctness just reduces to the definition of the data structure itself.

Comment: @user315052 I do not understand your objection, quite possibly because I am not smart enough for this kind of abstract thought. What I do feel is that algorithms operating over a data structure should not matter to this question since they do not change the way the data structure is defined -- e.g. a tree is a tree regardless of whether we use it as search tree or just as XML document.

Comment: @delnan: Let's look at it this way. A container needs to allow its contents to be retrievable. Furthermore, there must be a way to recognize that the retrieved contents correspond to contents that were inserted. Without such properties, there would be no way to verify the correctness of the container, and it becomes about as useful as `/dev/null`. If you don't consider that a searchable data structure, then we have no common ground for a discussion.

Comment: @user315052 I see where you are going (it appears I took "searchable" too literal/narrow). In any case, my feeble mind cannot follow. Count me out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the dynamic allocator itself is managing contiguous storage. Think about the "tape" used for a Turing Machine, or the Von Neumann architecture. So to seriously consider the problem, you would likely need to develop a new computing model and new computer architecture.

If you think disregarding the contiguous memory of the underlying machine is okay, I am sure a number of solutions are possible. The first that comes to my mind is that each node of the container is marked with an identifier that has no relation to its position in memory. Then, to find the associated node, all of memory is scanned until the identifier is found. This isn't even particularly inefficient if given enough computing elements in a parallel machine.

Comment: Ah, good point. But the data-structure programmer doesn't have to be aware that RAM is really just a huge array. With continuous memory I was referring to continuous memory **that is used as such**!

Comment: @bitmask: From that point of view, the programmer doesn't have to know how an array is actually implemented, as long as the index operator does what it advertises to do.

Comment: While this is true, I think that the distinction between memory usage of linked lists and arrays is sufficient to provide an interesting puzzle, even if all data structures merely map to a continuous memory backing.

Comment: @bitmask: I added a hypothetical data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch of a proof.

Given that a *program* must be of **finite size**, all types defined within the program must contain only finitely many *members* and reference only finitely many *other types*.  The same holds for any program entrypoint and for any objects defined before program initialisation.

In the absence of **contiguous arrays** (which are the *product* of a type with a *runtime natural number* and are therefore unconstrained in size), all types must be arrived at through the composition of types as above; derivation of types (pointer-to-pointer-to-`A`) is still constrained by the size of the program.  There are **no facilities** other than contiguous arrays to compose a runtime value with a type.

> This is a little contentious; if e.g. mappings are considered primitive then one can approximate an array with a map whose keys are the natural numbers.  Of course, any *implementation* of a map must use self-referential data structures (B-trees) or contiguous arrays (hash tables).

Next, if the types are **non-recursive** then any chain of types (`A` references `B` references `C`...) must terminate, and can be of no greater length than the number of types defined in the program.  Thus the total size of data *referenceable* by the program is limited to the product of the sizes of each type multiplied by the number of *names* defined in the program (in its entrypoint and static data).

This holds even if functions are recursive (which strictly speaking breaks the prohibition on recursive types, since functions are types); the amount of data *immediately visible* at any one point in the program is still limited to the product of the sizes of each type multiplied by the number of names visible at that point.

An exception to this is if you store a "container" in a **stack of recursive function calls**; however such a program would not be able to traverse its data at random without *unwinding* the stack and having to reread data, which is something of a disqualification.

Finally, if it is possible to **create types dynamically** the above proof does not hold; we could for example create a Lisp-style list structure where each cell is of a distinct type: `cons<4>('h', cons<3>('e', cons<2>('l', cons<1>('l', cons<0>('o', nil)))))`. This is not possible in most static-typed languages, although it is possible in some dynamic languages e.g. Python.

Comment: You're basically paraphrasing the core idea in König's lemma. At first I thought you were dead on, but if we allow continuous arrays, your assertion that we need recursive types would still hold which is obviously false. I believe this breaks your proof. Unfortunately -- it *was* elegant.

Comment: @bitmask I think I've rescued it, want to take another look?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not correct. The simple counter example is `std::deque` in C++. The basic data structure (for the language-agnostic part) is a contiguous array of pointers to arrays of data. The actual data is stored in *ropes* (non-contiguous blocks), that are chained through a contiguous array.

---

This might be bordering your requirements, depending on what *without using continuous memory areas* mean. I am using the interpretation that the stored data is not contiguous, but this data structure depends on having arrays for the intermediate layer.

Comment: Doesn't that still use continuous memory areas to store an arbitrarily large amount of data? Since either the array of arrays needs contain more arrays, or one of it's element arrays needs to gain more elements. Either way, you still use continuous memory areas.

Comment: I will not be convinced with this answer if I take *"without using continuous memory"* part seriously to the extent that avoids using *any* array.

Comment: If you ask me, this doesn't qualify. You are still using continuous storage. Obviously, I can store some intermediate type (that contains just one or any number of actual data objects) in the continuous sequence to avoid storing the data directly.

Comment: @bitmask: The problem is that your question is ill-posed. In some languages, even self referencing types are implemented in terms of arrays (i.e. the list interface can be implemented as an array). Now if what you want is strictly that, then a recursive template *is* a solution, since technically each instantiation of the template is a different type, the template refers to itself, but none of the types is self referencing. I am tempted to close as *Not a question*, as it is not clear what you really want to achieve

Comment: @bitmask: Also note the final question: *Are there data structures that are neither organised using mechanisms similar to linked lists / trees nor using continuous sequences exclusively?* ==> `std::deque`

Comment: Yes, the word "exclusively" is probably bogus and *technically* does qualify the `deque` as answer. Your point about recursive templates has the problem that the number of values I can store is fixed at compile time (or at least upper bounded).

Answer (score 0):

I think a better phrasing would be:

```
It's the only way to construct data structures (more precisely containers) that can accept 
arbitrary large data collections without using memory areas of determinable address.
```

What I mean is that normal arrays use `addr(idx)=idx*size+inital_addr` to get the memory address of an element. However, if you change that to something like `addr(idx)=idx*idx*size+initial_addr` then the elements of the data structure are not stored in continuous memory areas, rather, there are large gaps between where elements are stored. Thus, it is not continuous memory.

Comment: But you would still use continuous memory. It' just that you choose not to make use of most elements. You just waste memory intentionally -- if I understand you correctly.

Comment: No, you're not wasting memory. Let's say I'm the kernel, so I have access to all system memory. I could have an data structure, storing data in the above pattern. Then, when I map memory to user-level processes, I map the gaps in between the elements that I am using to user-mode memory.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well *then* your memory still *looks* like continuous for the user. I can access `addr(0)`, `addr(1)`, `addr(2)`, and so forth. What the kernel does with that is none of my concern (as far as this question is concerned).

Comment: I'm saying that the kernel is the sample program, but this still works for user-mode programs. Let's say the memory allocator (in user-mode) wants to store some data in a data structure. Then, whenever malloc() is called, it returns memory from in between elements of the data structure. In this case the memory doesn't look continuous to the program, and it doesn't matter, since malloc() results don't need to be continuous, so long as the pointer returned is continuous for the requested size.